# What listner I can use for filter

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I need to modify data which is used in filter. In sencha not getting any documentation on `Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters`. My question is what and all function I can use in listener of grid which affect the filter.

Comment: Please provide your ExtJS version. I haven't heard of Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters. Do you by chance mean [`Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature) or [`Ext.grid.filters.Filters`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.grid.filters.Filters.html)?

Comment: Extjs 3 I am using. I am writing in my generic like `Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters = Ext.extend(Ext.util.Observable` so in my code I can use `Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters `.